# forcing a rule of a url .htaccess static website

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am developing a static website that contains only .html files under the root folder (/public_html)

I am trying to force an URL rewriting rule here.

All Urls must be like : http://www.domain.com/file #rule 1

Other forms of writing must be rejected and treated as errors such as

http://www.domain.com/file.html #rule 2

http://www.domain.com/file/ # rule 3

Would you please help me  on this code

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

I succeed in the rules #1 and #3
Please help me on the rule #2, so when a visitor of my site type the url #2 he will be denied and never knows that ithis is a html file

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that you can use:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.